# Выборка полей во вложенных отношениях на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В официальной документации к Laravel есть пример где мы можем установить
дополнительные параметры при загрузке отношений, через ленивую загрузку.

Вот сам пример

`$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'login');
}])->get();`

Как мне тоже самое сделать для вложенных отношений? Допустим мне нужны поля только название книги, дата написания, и фамилия автора.

```
$users = App\User::with(['book.author'])->get();
```

Comment: Пока сделал следующим способом, не знаю насколько он правильный, мб кто подскажет способ покороче.

`
$users = App\User::with([
    'book' => function($query) { $query->select('name', 'create_date'); }
    'book.author' => function($query) { $query->select('fio'); }
])->get();`

Answer (score 3):

Ваш ответ в комментарии вполне можно использовать, можно облегчить использование в контроллере, если в самой модели создать новую связь по примеру уже написанной

```
public function bookCut()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Параметры связи)->select(['id', 'name', 'create_date']);
}

public function authorCut()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Параметры связи)->select(['id','fio']);
}
```

А затем использовать так:

```
$users = App\User::with(['bookCut.authorCut'])->get();
```

В select нужно добавить нужные поля вам на вывод и поля для работы связи (id, например)

Comment: Спасибо) Не знал что так можно)